# Disable filtering for NinePatchDrawables

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I am developing an app where the whole UI is drawn with scaled low res pixel art assets.
In order to draw backgrounds on views, I am overriding the "onSizeChanged" and creating a scaled drawable out of the existing view's drawable (with filtering set to false) as follows:

```
background = BitmapDrawable(context.resources, (background as BitmapDrawable).let {
        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( it.bitmap, w, h, false )
    })
```

This works very well and it's very unobtrusive. The problem arises when I try to achieve something similar for 9 patch images.

My current solution really sucks, I pass the drawable plus the top, right, left, bottom values, override the draw method of the given view (mostly for ViewGroups) and draw each piece of background manually using the same principle (scaled bitmap with filtering set to false).

While it kind of works (except for a few glitches on specific devices) it's not very flexible, requires lots of boilerplate every time I create a new view, I can't benefit from auto-generated .9 files and I'm pretty sure it's very inefficient. So I'm looking for simpler alternatives to achieve this.

I've been fiddling with custom NinePatchDrawable classes, where I set its Paint parameters on init:

```
paint.isFilterBitmap = false
paint.isAntiAlias = false
```

Then I feed those custom drawables into the view's background values. For some reason it seems that those parameters are being ignored (even though I can see them being passed down to the actual draw methods through the debugger). I tried to delve a bit deeper into the system's code responsible for rendering these drawables on canvas, but no luck and lots of dead ends...

Haven't found many resources about that (not really surprising, who's the crazy lad who wants to make their UI pixelated and jagged?!) and documentation isn't helping. Any clues?

edit: after researching a bit more I found that for my specific case the default 9 patch system would not work even with the antialiasing figured. I wanted the patch to "repeat" to fill the space instead of "stretch" which is the only option (see image below for clarity).

[image]

Comment: post your current code then

Comment: it wouldn't help with the question. I basically implemented my own version of a nine patch, whereas here I am asking for how to change the behaviour of the existing classes. also, there's nothing special about it, it's just a bunch of loops, math and drawing on canvas

Comment: `View v = new View(this);
        v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nine);
        setContentView(v);`

Comment: of course if you need some custom bounds to be drawn you need to get your `Drawable` , call `setBounds()` on it and finally call `Drawable#draw()` inside `View#onDraw` method

Comment: the "setLayerType" method did the trick about the filtering! (at least on the emulator) my only remaining problem now is being able to scale it to the right size before drawing the patches. I was hoping the drawable's draw method as you mentioned would help, but I'm not exactly sure how it works and the documentation isn't enlightening me so much...  I'm trying to fiddle with that on the view's onDraw, but no success so far

Comment: I was reading a bit further on the subject and apparently 9 patches don't support repeating (they will only stretch their contents) so the result I am looking for is not possible... I guess I'd better turn to my custom code in the end. your answer is still valid, though. setting the layer type on the view might be enough for most uses. if you post it as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: use `BitmapShader` + `Canvas#drawPaint()`